# How to solve the "3670: Cursor is not valid" Error in VB6.0

Tags: sql, vb6

I am working on an application on VB6. I am trying to execute a query but when I try to do an insert into a temporary table it gives me the error "Cursor is not valid." (I don't know if the insert is truly the problem, but from what I have tried it seems to be this).
The code is something like this: (this is not the correct query just an example)

```
 Dim p_C As Connection
 Dim p_R As Recordset
 Dim Sql As String
 Sql = "select d_start,d_finish,name from Table1"
 Sql= Sql & "where id=10"
 Sql=Sql & "Into #tempTable"
 Sql=Sql & "select * from #tempTable"
 Set p_R1 = p_C.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
  If Not p_R1.EOF Then
     'Do something
  End If
```

Now the p_R1.EOF gives **3670: cursor is not valid** error. If I delete the "Insert into #tempTable" string there is no error. Does anyone know what is the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: vb 6 is since very very long gone, it would be better to start with vb net which is stil supported in Visual Studi0 2022 and will be also in future

Comment: to your problem, you create a table and have so no records to retun, as such you don't can loop through it

Comment: @nbk but how is it possible because if I execute the query in SQL management studio it does return values

Comment: @nbk I have to do these in vb6 it is not really my choice

Comment: I'd start by doing a Debug.Print Sql before the OpenRecordset command to make sure that the Sql string is correct. - Although it's only an example that code wouldn't create valid Sql because there are no spaces between the parts of the statement.

Comment: There's **no whitespace** between those concatenated strings. So you have `from Table1where id=10`. Note the missing gap between `table1` and `where`. The other concatenated lines have the same issue. The line break between the code lines is not part of the resulting string.

Comment: Been a while since I worked with DAO (if you do stay with vb6, a change to ADO is worth considering), but I recall that dbOpenSnapShot flag will create a read-only result, but the Select-Into requires writing to a new table, so perhaps that is the cause of the error?  You could try dbOpenDynamic or dbOpenDynaset instead.

Comment: @MarkL That's correct. dbOpenSnapshot is readonly so the "Cursor is not valid" error is correct if the OP is trying to insert data. See the Remarks section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-dao

Comment: @MarkL I tried using dbOpenDynamic or dbOpenDynaset the problem still persists

Comment: @MarkL this is my first time working with vb6 , so how can I switch the code below from DAO to ADO?

Comment: Just in case, check the query with the table ``##tempTable`` (global temporary table).

Comment: @ValNik Yess thank you very much this solved it. I just divided the query.

Comment: It's what Joel said. There is no whitespace.

Comment: @StayOnTarget I had added the whitespace in my code (I forgot to put it in this example here sorry) but it was not that the problem.

Comment: Got it. You can edit your question to fix that, it would make it all much more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim p_C As Connection
 Dim p_R As Recordset
 Dim Sql As String
 Sql = "select d_start,d_finish,name "
 Sql= Sql & "Into ##tempTable "
 Sql= Sql & "from Table1 "
 Sql= Sql & " where id=10; "
 p_C.Execute Sql
 Sql=""
 Sql= Sql & "select * from ##tempTable"
 Set p_R1 = p_C.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
 If Not p_R1.EOF Then
 'Do something
 End If
```

The problem persisted with the insert statement so I just divided the query. This works very well. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: And you also added whitespace - was that the main issue?

Comment: @StayOnTarget no I had already added the whitespace in my code(I forgot to show it here) but it was not that the problem.

Comment: Probably it should be like this  ``Sql= Sql & "select * from ##tempTable"``  ?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are to kind of temporary SQL tables: #session and ##global. So in your example #tempTable and ##tempTable are kinda _two different_ tables. See https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-temporary-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement has some errors, you should test the sql statements in ssms

it must be

```
 select d_start,d_finish,name 
 Into #tempTable
from Table1
 where id=10;
  select * from #tempTable
```

in vb 6

```
Sql = "select d_start,d_finish,name "
Sql= Sql & "Into #tempTable "
Sql= Sql & "from Table1 "
Sql= Sql & " where id=10; "
Sql= Sql & "select * from #tempTable"
```

Comment: yes thank you, however even like this it still gives the error.

Comment: run the sql code directly in ssms and see if ut runs on the sql server directly

Comment: yeah it seems to not be the string the problem